# how to calculate on real time?

Tags: android, listener

I want to create calculator which have 2 edit text name input1 and input2 and have spinner which show the operand so I try

```
input1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            calculate();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but it's not on time , I have to press back space 1 time in any edittext to calculate it

I think the problem is "onKey" function

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the calculations to happen on the fly, and you don't have need for a button.

If that is true, you could attach a TextWatcher to each EditText via the [addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method.  Whenever you receive an event from it, you can call calculate().  In this instance you would probably also want to attach an AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener to your Spinner.

If you ARE using a button to do your calculations, you would simply have a button, give it an OnClickListener which would call your calculate method.